# disable plaintext password in ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a openldap server v3 that is storing passwords in plain text, is there anyway by which we can change the password to be stored in SSHA format by default. I use Apache DS to login to the directory tree and i see the user passwords in plaintext which in turn is a security keyhole for my firm. Please suggest as to how i enable forced SSHA password mechanism and turn of clear text.

Let me know if anyone needs more data from my side to answer this. Many thanx in advance.

Regards
Niraj

Comment: You should ask it on Server Fault

Answer (score 1):

Use the Password Policy overlay and specify hashing of plaintext passwords:

```
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_hash_cleartext
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. As a layman in ldap can you suggest me how to apply this setting.

Comment: In `slapd.conf,` but if you don't know how to configure OpenLDAP you're the wrong person to be asking this question anyway.